# ExtJS 5 how to dynamically create fields in model

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, field, extjs5

I have plenty of fields that I want to add to my model. I fount this thread [Dynamic Model with ExtJS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751289/dynamic-model-with-extjs-4) but in 5th version there is no method setFields for the model.

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694959/dynamic-model-manipulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for everybody, I used method addFields() and made it in this way:

```
var model = Ext.ClassManager.get('app.model.GridModel');
var fields = [];
fields.push({ name: 'param', type: 'string' });
for (var i=1; i<20; i++){
   fields.push({ name: 'name', type: 'string'});
}
model.addFields(fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ext.data.Model.setConfig()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-setConfig) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`replaceFields` method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-replaceFields), though.

Note that this won't magically create the field data any existing models, though.